# Convert m/d/yyyy H:MM:SS am/pm to "month d, yyyy" in SQL

Tags: mysql

How to convert {7/4/2016 5:00:00 Am} to "July 4, 2016" in SQL. This has to be done in SQL only as I need to send the date as in {7/4/2016 5:00:00 Am} format and need to store and retrieve back in "July 4, 2016" format.

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2012.

Comment: Did you even bother trying to look at the docs? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: "sql-server" refers to Microsoft SQL Server which is not MySQL related.

Comment: Hi Adam, we do like it if new posters make an effort here. For your next question, please consider adding a code sample, even if it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If SQL Server 2012+ you can use the format() function

```
select format(cast('7/4/2016 5:00:00 Am' as datetime),'MMMM d, yyyy')

Returns 
July 4, 2016
```